# Google DNS Same Entry Different Results

Tags: domain-name-system, google

Why is this happening?

The Rootserver returns a wrong entry I fixed containing `5269.XXX.com.` instead of `5269 XXX.com.`

Macbook @ Home

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 srv _xmpp-server._tcp.XXX.com.    
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18412
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_xmpp-server._tcp.XXX.com. IN SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_xmpp-server._tcp.XXX.com. 64328 IN SRV 10 0 5269 XXX.com.

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 28 03:16:45 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86
```

Rootserver

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 srv _xmpp-server._tcp.XXX.com.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27240
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_xmpp-server._tcp.XXX.com. IN  SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_xmpp-server._tcp.XXX.com. 52139 IN SRV 0 10 0 5269.XXX.com.

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 28 03:23:23 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 91
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I'm using the Google DNS in Frankfurt and the Rootserver the Google DNS in Berlin

http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq.html#locations

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the DNS entries to propagate. It depends on your TTL that you set for the record.

Comment: Hi malfy... indeed, but that still doesn't explain why different results are returned.

Comment: Maybe one of the hosts is caching the DNS entry? That is all I can think of at the moment. Give a bit more detail on how you are testing these records, Macbook@Home, and you tested it again from that same Macbook?